# subprocess (reg query...) not always running. Very odd issue

Tags: windows, python-2.7, tkinter

Hopefully someone will be able to assist me with this very weird and annoying issue.

Background: I have a tkinter gui with a number of functions on. One of which is to view the registry keys (using reg query) on a specified remote pc and output the display to a text widget below. It is designed to be run and re-run, starting at the top level (hklm) with each output having line numbers for you to choose which reg key to open next. Below is the code for this function.

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkMessageBox import *
import subprocess

root = Tk()
root.title("PC Admin GUI")
root.geometry("{}x{}".format(670, 790))

entryframe = Frame(root)
entryframe.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, pady=(5, 0))

Label(entryframe, text="Enter Computer Name :").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, padx=(5, 0), pady=(8, 0))
pcnameEntry = Entry(entryframe, width=25)
pcnameEntry.focus_set()
pcnameEntry.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, pady=(0, 10), padx=5)


regframe = Frame(root)
regframe.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W, pady=(5, 0))

Label(regframe, text="Enter Reg Key/No :").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, padx=(5, 0), pady=5)
regEntry = Entry(regframe, width=18)
regEntry.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, pady=(0, 10), padx=(5, 0))

def query():
    pcName = pcnameEntry.get()
    pcName = pcName.upper()
    if len(regEntry.get()) == 0:
        showwarning("Warning", "No entry detected.")
        return
    regInput = regEntry.get()
    if regInput in ("hklm", "hku"): # the only keys available for remote pcs
        ping_out = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-n", "1", pcName],stdout = subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
        if ('unreachable' in ping_out):
            showwarning("Warning", "PC not responding.")
        else:
            outputText.delete(0.0,END)
            regOut = subprocess.Popen(r"reg query \\" + pcName + "\\" + regInput, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            data, error = regOut.communicate()
            data = data.strip().split("\n")
            count = 1
            for line in data:
                outputText.insert("end", str(count) + "   " + line + "\n")
                count += 1
            outputText.insert("end", "\nEnter line number above to continue.")
            regEntry.delete(0,END)
    elif regInput in ("hkcr", "hkcu", "hkcc", "hkpd"):
        showwarning("Warning", "Not a valid hive for a remote machine.")
        regEntry.delete(0,END)
    else:
        regList = outputText.get(1.0, "end-1c")
        regList = regList.strip("Enter line number above to continue.")
        regList = regList.strip().split("\n")
        for line in regList:
            if line.startswith(regInput):
                line = line.split(" ", 3)[-1]
                print line # Works - Shows correct line from list
                print (r"reg query \\" + pcName + "\\" + line) # Works - Shows full command. Can copy/paste to cmd and run ok
                outputText.delete(0.0,END) # Fails after this point.
                regOut = subprocess.Popen(r"reg query \\" + pcName + "\\" + line, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
                data, error = regOut.communicate()
                print regOut # Works. Shows different subprocess object number each time
                print data # Fails - does nothing
                print error # Error "Unable to find specified reg key"
                data = data.strip().split("\n")
                count = 1
                for lines in data:
                    outputText.insert("end", str(count) + "   " + lines + "\n")
                    count += 1
                outputText.insert("end", "\nEnter line number above to continue.")
                regEntry.delete(0,END)

regQuery_but = Button(regframe, text="Query", width=7, height=1, command=query)
regQuery_but.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W, padx=5)

outputframe = Frame(root)
outputframe.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W, pady=(5, 0))

Label(outputframe, text="Output :").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, padx=5, pady=(10, 0))

outputText = Text(outputframe, height=32, width=65, bg="black", fg="white")
scrollbar = Scrollbar(outputframe)
scrollbar.config(command=outputText.yview)
outputText.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
outputText.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=(10, 5), padx=(5, 0))
scrollbar.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=N+S)
```

The first level works okay - entering hklm (or hku) will show the first 6 top level reg hives. Entering a line number should then display the next level, but for some reason it only works if you select the last line! You can keep selecting the last lines and go through the whole tree, But if you enter any of the other line numbers, it claims it cannot find the reg key.

You can see a number of 'print' lines in the code - these are for debugging to try and see where the problem is. It will display the correct chosen line and the full command that it's about to run (which can be copied into cmd and will run fine), so I cannot see why when the subprocess tries to run the command it fails (unless you've chosen the last line of the prev output!)

I hope this makes sense - it's not an easy problem to discribe. You should be able to see by running it yourselves.

P.S. Apologies about the title of this question - I couldn't come up with anything better...

Comment: Is regEntry the Entry() to get the line number?  It doesn't appear to be.  Print "regList" after this line as you overwrite/re-declare it as a string  regList = regList.strip("Enter line number above to continue.") so will never equal a line number, and I see no additional Entry widget to enter the line number or a button to get the line entry but I may have missed it.

Comment: In the above, it should say that the strip() won't strip anything unless that string is at the beginning or end of the line, which says there could still be white space that is causing the problem and would not be easy to spot.  Add a .strip() to  "line" in the regOut = subprocess.Popen(...+ line.strip()...)  And note that r"reg query \\" leaves the 2 backslashes as 2 backslashes.

Comment: @CurlyJoe - Thanks for replying!   Yes, the same entry is used for both the initial entry (hklm/hku) and the line numbers.    I don't think it's a white space issue as the print lines show the correct information, and the thing does run perfectly, providing I pick the correct line!   And yes, r"reg query \\" is correct - it needs 2 \\'s in the command.

Comment: Does anyone else have any answers on this issue? It's really causing me a problem at the mo... Thanks.